# What is a measure?

Tags: haskell, liquid-haskell

I am reading [this](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/tpfa.pdf) where I find this:

> **Measures** -- In order to allow Haskell functions to appear in refinement
>   types, we need to lift them to the refinement type level.

And there are other documents asserting that *measures* are needed to use such function in contract. But I tried this:

```
{-@ len :: List a -> Nat @-}
len :: List a -> Int
len Nil           = 0
len (x `Cons` xs) = 1 + len xs

{-@ mymap :: (a -> b) -> xs : List a -> { ys : List b | len xs == len ys } @-}
mymap :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
mymap _ Nil           = Nil
mymap f (x `Cons` xs) = f x `Cons` mymap f xs
```

and this works but `len` is not *measure*. So what is measure exactly and when I need it?

---

Another example which does not work without `measure`:

```
{-@ measure ln @-}
ln :: [a] -> Int
ln [] = 0
ln (x:y) = 1 + ln y

{-@ conc :: xs : [a] -> ys : [a] -> {zs : [a] | ln zs == ln xs + ln ys} @-}
conc :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
conc [] ys = ys
conc (x:xs) ys = x : (conc xs ys)
```

Usage of `{-@ measure length @-}` like I found in many documents leads to error `Cannot extract measure from haskell function` (ie. from `length`).

Comment: Correct syntax to declare length as measure is `{-@ measure length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int @-}`. Seems LH does not see it's signature by default..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A measure is just a function that can be run by LiquidHaskell at verification time, to be used in refinements and termination checking. You likely already knew this.

The reason your first example "works" (I think it's incomplete as-is, but I can tell what you were going for) is that `len` is already defined as a measure [in the LiquidHaskell prelude](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/blob/211445762c9127e2f0e7d090978c844300fd1dfe/include/GHC/Base.spec#L12) (technically it's a "class measure", which means it's polymorphic, and thus can be used both with `[]` lists and your custom `List`). Assuming you've added annotations for `Nil` and `Cons` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327061) from your earlier question, the `len` used in the refinement for `mymap` is not your `len`, but the prelude `len`, which is already a measure.

In your second example, `measure` is required because `ln` is a new symbol in the measure namespace, and doesn't exist unless you make it.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense, and especially predefined `len`.